# Diagram to evaluate multiple metrics for different models

Tags: python, metrics, diagram, evaluation

I want to use python to plot a diagram like the one in the image below. The purpose of it is to summarize the results of different models using multiple metrics to evaluate.
Is there a way to easily do it in Python, if not can someone refer me to the name of the diagram or a framework I can do it?

[image: performance of multiple metrics different models]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to draw is called a [radar chart.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart)

[matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/specialty_plots/radar_chart.html) allows the drawing of such a chart.

The matplotlib example above is quite verbose and there may be other, simpler solutions out there. But hopefully, knowing the name of the type of chart will help you in your search. Best of luck!